# How to a avoid MATLAB round values when I save them as csv file?

Tags: matlab, csvwriter

I used  csvwrite function.
The original input vector's elements increase by 0.001: 0 , 001, 002....but when I save it as csv file the excel shows values like this at bigger numbers: 99.999, 100, 100, 100, etc. Changing the data format in excel doesn't solve the problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. CSV is a text format; verify loss of precision in a text editor.
Excel is not acclaimed for accuracy.
2. As was already mentioned, csv is a text format. You can write arbitrarily precise data using a text file function (such as fprintf), adding commas as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to its [help page](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html), `csvwrite` has the following limitations:

> `csvwrite` writes a maximum of five significant digits. If you need greater precision, use [`dlmwrite`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) with a precision argument.

However, both functions are no longer recommended by MathWorks, but the use of [`writetable`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html), [`writematrix`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html), or [`writecell`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writecell.html) is encouraged instead.